# Laravel and MySQL / Facebook Relay and schema, anyone trying this?

Tags: mysql, laravel, schema, relayjs

I'd be interested to see if anyone is trying this combination of technology. I've started working on a Laravel Project, but curious with the capabilities of Facebook Relay. So user still post data the usual way to MySQL but on retrieving data, using Facebook Relay to tranform the Front-End of the page.

Comment: This looks promising [Teaching servers to speak GraphQL](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/14/community-roundup-27.html), I've already been experimenting with bookshelf.js and MySQL, been working well.